# Can we update multiple record with join of two query

Tags: oracle

Can we run Update query to update multiple records with join ?
Below query is working fine when we running with one employee number -

```
update java set JAVA_MECHANISM='RECONCILIATION' 
where usr_key =(select usr_key from usr 
where usr_emp_no='******' and usr_status='Active') 
and JAVA_MECHANISM= 'ACCESS';
```

Now requirement is want to run this query with all users who exist with where filter of 2 tables `where usr.usr_status='Active' and java.JAVA_MECHANISM= 'ACCESS';`  i.e.

```
update oiu set OIU_PROV_MECHANISM='RECONCILIATION',
POL_KEY=null, OIU_POLICY_BASED=null,
OIU_POLICY_REVOKE=null 
where usr_key IN(select usr_key from usr where usr_status='Active' 
and usr_udf_isexecutiveuser='1') 
and OIU_PROV_MECHANISM = 'AP HARVESTED';
```

it’s taking too much time more than 10 mins but not completed as IN takes much time so any idea how we can get with oracle query ???

Comment: How many rows are being affected? Can you post the Plan, please?  (Both `update` and `merge`)  Does the cardinality of the Plan match expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try `merge` instead, e.g.

```
merge into oiu o
  using (select u.usr_key
         from user u
         where u.usr_status = 'Active'
           and u.usr_udf_isexecutiveuser = '1'
        ) x
  on (o.usr_key = x.usr_key)
  when matched then update set
    o.oiu_prov_mechanism = 'RECONCILIATION',
    o.pol.key = null,
    o.oiu_policy_based = null,
    o.oiu_policy_revoke = null
  where o.oiu_prov_mechanism = 'AP HARVESTED';
```